# How to add External data type column in a sharepoint list using powershell script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I want to add a new column with the data type External Data type in a list in SharePoint site using powershell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the the Answer.

We can use AddFieldAsXml() method to create.

Code:

```
 $mainCollegeColXml = "<Field Type='BusinessData' DisplayName='MainCollege' ... />"
 $spList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($mainCollegeColXml,$true,
     [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
 $spList.Update()
```